# Black screen, apparently caused by touchscreen

Tags: 14.04, dell, touchscreen

Sometimes my screen goes black, I think it happens when I touch the touchscreen but it happens like once every ten minutes so I can't be sure.

I'm running ubuntu 14.04 on a Dell xps 13 2015, and I don't know what else to give you.

To solve the problem I have to close the laptop and reopen it.
When it happens, both the computer and the screen are still awake, it just goes black.

Thanks

Comment: it happens to me even with no using touchscreen, I've updated kernel to 3.19, previously it didn't occur

Comment: @jangorecki Indeed it happens also when I'm not doing anything! You haven't found any solutions yet ? I've updated to ubuntu 14.10 but it hasn't solved the problem

Comment: I'm having the same issue. My screen will go black even w/o my doing anything. Closing the laptop and reopening it solves the issue but that's getting old, especially when I have to do that 5 times in 10 minutes. The laptop is an Asus UX302LA running kernel 3.15.0-031500rc8-generic. I upgraded to that kernel because it was the only one that I have found so far where the screen brightness buttons work. Update: I just upgraded to kernel 3.16 and so far so good.

Comment: I'm already on 3.16, it doesn't change anything.. But indeed, I think it is a kernel related problem..